# Wicket: set JodaDateTime from form

Tags: java, forms, hibernate, wicket

Im using wicket and hibernate for developing a website. I simply want to save some data of a form.
My Object is like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="DISCRIMINATOR",discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING )
@DiscriminatorValue(value="product")
public class Product implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "PRODUCT_ID")
private int productID;

@Column(name = "START_DATE")
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
private DateTime startDate;

public DateTime getStartDate() {
    return startDate;
}

public void setStartDate(DateTime startDate) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
}
}
```

I got a form where, inside that form are several input fields. For date fields I use:

```
DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
DateConverter dateConverter = new PatternDateConverter ( "dd.MM.yyyy", false );

final DateTextField startDate = new DateTextField("startDate",dateConverter);
startDate.add(datePicker);
```

If I submit the form I get this exception:

```
 Last cause: Could not convert value: 08.10.14 to type: org.joda.time.DateTime. Could not find     compatible converter.
WicketMessage: Method onFormSubmitted of interface     org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.IFormSubmitListener targeted at [Form [Component id = form]] on     component [Form [Component id = form]] threw an exception
```

I guess its because wicket uses the setter for startDate. But how can I edit this?

Comment: Does your form use `CompoundPropertyModel`? If true, then I think it tries to convert `Date` to `DateTime` and it fails. Try to use custom model for your `DateTextField` ( for example`new PropertyModel<Date>(this,"customDate")` ) to store real value with `Date` object, and when form submits -> convert that `customDate` to `DateTime` object and set to `Product`.

Comment: When storing a `DateTextField` I'm using `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)` instead of `@Type` and then I'm using a `Date` object `private Date startDate;`. You can also set `TemporalType` to `Date`

Comment: Hey, I think I realized that I did not understand models exactly yet. I added to my DateTextField a Model of Date as @Michael said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `CompoundPropertyModel` for your form, then form components will search for a corresponding fields of the real model object, to apply values to (wicket:id of the form component must be equals to the name of the model's field and type of this field must be same as form component returns).

But if there is no corresponding field in model, or we want to use independent form component, then we just need to use another model for such component.

Your exception appeared due to the fact that `DateTextField` returns `Date` after convertion and your model have `DateTime` field.

So, you have at least two ways to deal with this:

1. Described in my comment way to use custom model for this field and convert `Date` value, fetched from form component at `onSubmit` method, to `DateTime` object.
2. But, I think it is better to use your own converter. You can force your `DateTextField` to return `DateTime` object for your model. Look [here](http://wicket.apache.org/guide/guide/forms2.html#forms2_3) or [here](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples-6.0.x/forminput/?1) (see URL `TextField` in src) for better understanding of how to achive this. You can implement your own converter relying to `org.apache.wicket.datetime.DateConverter` src.